# 422 (Unprocessable Entity): Web-Worker w/ JS Frontend & Rails Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-worker

I am trying to create a JS utility library that uses a web-worker. My application has a ReactJS FE and a RoR backend. This is the first time I've worked w/ Web Workers and am essentially a beginner in RoR, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly.

My current folder/file structure for the web worker inside my React JS app is like so:

```
web-worker-lib >
 - utils
   - my-web-worker.js
   - main.js

app.js
```

And within my main.js, I attempt to instantiate my web-worker as so:

```
const my_web_worker = new Worker('my-web-worker.js');

export function foo() { 
  const list = ['1','2','3'];
  const my_web_worker_message = {
    numbers:     list
  }
  my_web_worker.postMessage(my_web_worker_message);
}
```

In my app's main App.js file, I try calling the function with my already instantiated web-worker as so:

```
import { foo } from './web-worker-lib/utils/main';

const render = (...) => {
  // ... 
  foo();
  // ...
}
```

So `foo()` should be called after each render, however I get the following error from Rails once the page attempts to render:

> ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest at /my-web-worker.js
> Security warning: an embedded  tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

And

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

I tried fixing this through my Rails CORS configuration file, however it hasn't helped (I'm probably doing it wrong):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins ...
    resource 'my-web-worker.js', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options], credentials: true
```

I've also read a bit about the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)  , but I'm a bit confused by it. I see under my Network's tab that the request URL seems to comply with the policy:

`Request URL: http://localhost:3400/my-web-worker.js`

I'm hoping someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong or if anyone has worked with Web Workers in a similar stack. Please, I will appreciate any help with this.